# South migration in django

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I added a new field in an existing model in django. Note that this app is already converted to south. To apply my new changes I ran these commands

```
   python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto
   python manage.py migrate my_app
```

This is giving an error like  **"Table 'database.south_migrationhistory' doesn't exist"**.

So I try to migrate south.

```
   python manage.py syncdb
   python manage.py migrate south
```

But this results in the same error **"Table 'database.south_migrationhistory' doesn't exist"**.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Which version of Django is that? `south` is deprecated.

Comment: @Selcuk Django version-1.6 South version-1.0.2